# Difference between for with brackets and without

Tags: java

Why compiler works fine with:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) { Object obj = new Object(); }
```

but doesn't compile this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) Object obj = new Object();
```

For me it's semantically equal statements. Why's the first statement compile?